# Test Rail Exporting Images

Tags: image, export, testrail

My software company is considering moving from a proprietary Testing Tool towards using Test Rail for our test cases. Our research indicates Test Rail has the ability to export test cases via XML, CSV, and Excel.

For Test Case validation we want to provide our customers a copy of the test case using any of the mentioned formats however we also want to include the validated image screenshots. Each test case have have 20-80 executed screenshots. We would like to export each executed test case plus their respective images. The issue is Test Rail appears to not support the export of said images.

Does anyone have a 3rd party tool to resolve this?